# iOS code to dismiss a View with countdown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Im experimenting with iOS 8 Objective-c project to perform a segue to a view controller right when viewDidLoad is presented.

Then this recent new presented view should be dismissed by a 30 seconds countdown to return to the initial view controller.

What would be like the code to dismiss the view with a countdown ? A countdown interface would not be necessary, just the background code.

My initial view controller is called ConfViewController and will perform a segue right on viewDidLoad to BubbleViewController, this should be displayed for 30s then be dismissed to the first one again ConfViewController.

```
@implementation ConfViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

The BubbleViewController

```
@interface BubbleViewController ()

@end

@implementation MessagesViewController {
  UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  self.dataSource = self;
  self.delegate = self;

  [super viewDidLoad];
```

Thnx and cheers!

Comment: I guess Prince's answer should achieve the desired results. Another way to do is using `NSTimer` to trigger a selector which will dismiss the current view controller.

Comment: Hi Krishna, thnx for the reply. Now Im having problems to call my second view controller "Bubble" right after the first ConfViewController is created. I tried to create a segue in viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear(from the first view controller) but it crashes. I could only perform the direct segue on viewDidAppear the problem is when I dismiss this second BubbleViewController the viewDidAppear from the first view controller calls the second again, I get a loop.

Comment: So what I need is to call the second view controller right after the first shows but should be able to return to the first without the loop. Any  code suggestion ?

Comment: I figure it out! Using viewDidLoad. I a tab bar button that points to the ConfviewController(first view) so I used the button selector action in viewDidLoad to call BubbleViewController(second view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this Code into your bubble view Controllers viewDidLoad or similar and it will dismiss itself after 30 seconds:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(30 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: It would be possible to implement on that view with the dispatch a switch controller to turn the timer on/off right ?

Comment: You mean having a switch in the UI which you can use to stop the view from disappearing? Yes that would be possible but you should probably use NSTimer to handle that instead of GCD.

Comment: Yes. Im having problems to load my second view above the first right after the first view is created. Like to load the BubbleViewController on top of ConfViewController right after this one is created. Should I use performWithSegue in viewDidLoad ? Could you suggest a code ? Thnx very much!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to execute any code after some time is to use this snippet:

`dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //code to be executed after a specified delay
    });`

Where you should place this code is up to you either in the presenters  or in the presented controllers `viewDidLoad`.

How you should dismiss it depends on the way that you presented it.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line of code in `BubbleViewController's` `viewDidLoad` method

```
//countdown can be according to requirement
[self performSelector:@selector(dissmissView) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
```

Now description of `dissmissView` method and add these method also.

```
-(void)dissmissView
{
    if (self.navigationController.presentingViewController)
    {
       //presented As ModaL
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if(self.navigationController)
    {
       //Pushed in navigation controller stack
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else //added as subView
    {
       [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```